# Semantic UI (React): Responsive vertical menu by changing to horizontal on mobile devices

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, semantic-ui, semantic-ui-react

I am using a vertical menu (`semantic ui react`). This is my structure for that:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.Column mobile={16} tablet={5} computer={5}>
        <div className='ui secondary pointing menu vertical compact inherit'>
            <a className='item'>
                Element
            </a>
        </div>
    </Grid.Column>
</Grid>
```

But I need the menu to become a horizontal icon menu on mobile devices. Is it possible to make it in this way responsive? I mean on computer it should be a vertical menu with text items and on mobile devices it should be displayed horizontal with icons...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you're looking for [stackable menu](http://react.semantic-ui.com/collections/menu#stackable) variation. Also, you can use Grid's [visibility](http://react.semantic-ui.com/collections/grid#device-visibility) for more complex things.

Comment: But I think `stackable` is the other way round. Default should be a vertical menu and on mobile it should become horizontal...

Comment: Oh, my miss :( I've made codepen that shows [visibility power](https://codepen.io/layershifter/pen/jyvpXZ).

Comment: Good but is there a one with a burger button?

Answer (score 1):

I have been looking for responsive react semantic-ui menu and this looks good, collapses with a hamburger icon

https://codesandbox.io/s/325y47xk36

Comment: This will render children twice, one for the mobile and one for the desktop. Only one of them will be visible depending on the device. However, the other one will be on the HTML and may cause issues.